# Why is my false argument not counted as false?

Tags: node.js

I have a parameter from the request that is false, but it isnt being detected as false... My code looks like this:

```
router.post('/leave', (req, res) => {
    const myBooleanValue = req.body.myBooleanValue
    console.log(myBooleanValue) // This prints out 0
    if (!myBooleanValue) {
        // This bit never gets called
    }
})
```

As you can see, `myBooleanValue` is `0`, indicating false. However, the inner code of the if clause never gets called as it doesn't detect it as being false. I've also tried `if (myBooleanValue === 0) {}` and `if (myBooleanValue === false) {}`. But that doesn't work. Help please?

Comment: did you try `parseInt(myBooleanValue) === 0`

Comment: Very probable that `myBooleanValue` is string type. (!"0") does not count as true

Comment: If you have control of the client, try sending `false` instead of `"0"`

Comment: Thanks everyone, you were all correct!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure its not coming back as a literal `'0'`. If it is coming back as a literal than cast it to an int by doing

```
const myBooleanValue = parseInt(req.body.myBooleanValue);

if (myBooleanValue === 0) {
        // This bit never gets called
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that the type of `myBooleanValue` is string, not number. `!"0" === false`. You could do type coercion `if (!(+myBooleanValue))`